# Transform an array of coordinates into polygon react-leaflet and get bounds of it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, polygon, react-leaflet

I'm having trouble with using L of leaflet and its features. I have an array of a polygon, but I don't know how to move map to the center of the polygon. I researched on leaflet and found polygon.getBounds() and map.fitBound(polygon.getBounds()) can solve my problem. However, I don't know how to use it in react-leaflet. Can you show me how to solve this ? Thanks in advance.
My code :

```
function MyComponent() {
    const map = useMap()
    const polygonMap=L.polygon(polygon.geometry.coordinates).addTo(map)
    if(polygon.geometry){
      console.log(polygon.geometry.coordinates)
      map.fitBounds(polygonMap.getBounds())
    }
    return null
  }
```

'polygon.geometry.coordinates' return an array of points of the polygon. I want to transform it into a leaflet polygon and use getBounds() to get its center point on map.

Comment: It should work the way you are trying to do it. The question is when you want to zoom the map to the polygon. When the map loads, when you press a btn, when you receive the `polygon.geometry.coordinates`? Try using an `effect` or `useMapEvents`

Comment: I fixed it successfully. Thank you !